# Is it a good idea to use Oracle 11g Client against a 10g database for Oracle Advanced Queuing?

Tags: oracle, nservicebus, advanced-queuing

I am developing some integration software for a client using amongst other things, C#, NServiceBus and Oracle 10g (client and server).  The requirement is that I need to develop a new plugin for NServiceBus to create an implementation of ITransport which is the queuing mechanism for the messages.  So Oracle Advanced Queuing is used for this.  I have done quite a bit of work writing code for advanced queuing in Oracle 11g (client and server), but looking at ODP.Net 10g it seems that the queuing support is lacking or non-existent so that may prove to be problematic.

My question is this:

I know that you can use the 11g client against a 10g database server, but is it a good idea for Oracle Advanced Queuing and are there any gotchas I need to know about?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a good idea for Advanced Queueing?  Well, I don't see why not, since 11g client connecting to 10g server is supported.

I don't imagine that AQ would pose any unique problem, specific to AQ.  If you think about it, AQ is just PL/SQL calls that interact with tables under the covers.  There's really nothing different at the client side, than there is with any other Oracle code.

So, I say go for it.  But, as always:  Test, test test.  And then test some more.

But, in principle, I don't see a problem.

Comment: Yeah, thanks Mark, when you put it that way it sounds a lot less scary!  I'll do some more testing tomorrow and see what comes out.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the [NServiceBus-Contrib](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus-Contrib) project, as there is an AQS transport there for 2.x.

Comment: I have had a look at that, seems to be just what I need.  I did have a few problems around the distributed transactions and moving messages to the error queue.  I am going to have a good look at it today starting with your AQS transport and I'll let you know how I get on.  I have also created a Saga persister for Oracle which seems to be working quite well - just a few locking issues I need to sort out.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad you have expanded the implementation and look forward to checking out the Saga.